# Replace symbol in jquery input and multiply everything by 2 if a checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, replace, keyup

I need help with the following line:

```
kilometros = kilometros.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");
```

And also know how I can multiply this by 2 if a `checkbox` is selected, thanks for your quick response!

```
$('#kilometros').keyup(function() { 

   var kilometros = parseFloat($(this).val());

   kilometros = kilometros.toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");

   var precioKilometros = parseFloat($('#precioKilometros').val());
   var totalKilometros = (kilometros * precioKilometros).toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");      
    $('#totalKilometros').html(totalKilometros);

});
```

Problem solved (the only thing missing is multiplied by 2 when a checkbox is selected):

```
$('#kilometros').keyup(function() { 
       var kilometros = parseFloat($(this).val().toString().replace(",", "."));
       var precioKilometros = parseFloat($('#precioKilometros').val());
       var totalKilometros = (kilometros * precioKilometros).toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");      
        $('#totalKilometros').html(totalKilometros);
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with that line?

Comment: final code: http://jsfiddle.net/erichmuller/3k9sz/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a multiplier based on whether your `checkbox` is checked

```
var multiplier = 1.0;

if($("#checkbox[checked]") !== null)
{
    multiplier = 2.0;
}
```

then apply it to your calculation

Also - not really an answer to the first part of your question but typically you should keep the data separated from the formatting.  Calculations should not have to contend with filtering formatting to make the calculation work.

Comment: Hey @fnostro, thanks for the reply, but it does not work, idk what im doing wrong:

$('#kilometros').keyup(function() {       
       var kilometros = parseFloat($(this).val().toString().replace(",", "."));
    var precioKilometros = parseFloat($('#precioKilometros').val());
    
    var retorno = 1.0;
       if($("#retorno[checked]") !== null)
          {
            var retorno = 2.0;
          }
    
       var totalKilometros = (kilometros * precioKilometros * retorno).toFixed(2).toString().replace(".", ",");    
        $('#totalKilometros').html(totalKilometros);
  
});

Comment: What is the html of the `retorno` checkbox?  The code that reads `$("#retorno[checked]")` replace `#retorno` with the id of the checkbox control

Comment: I was able to solve it, thank you very much http://jsfiddle.net/erichmuller/3k9sz/4/